# Connecting Azure blob storage to PowerApps

Tags: azure-storage, powerapps

I know it is possible to use blob storage as a data source in PowerApps, but  is it possible to get data from e.g Excel that is stored in a blob and show it on a form?

Comment: I think it is possible, but I would never use Excel as a data source for PowerApps.  See [here](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/29/powerapps-101-data-storage/).

Comment: If it was up to me I probably wouldn't either. I tried connecting the blob storage and is shows it as datasource but when trying to get the table data to a combobox it doesnt show up at all. Got it to work  with File storage but the same doesn't apply to blob storage.

Answer (score 1):

Currently using Excel stored in blob storage is not possible in PowerApps. You can consider creating a new feature request for this in the [PowerApps Ideas board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas).

Comment: Thanks! I just spoke with a staff member and it seems they had a connector(s) but the connector schema changed and its uncertain if it / they work anymore